# disable vertical scrolling on a div/img

Tags: css, html, browser, horizontal-scrolling

I have a header on my website with a large image ( 1000px width ).
This image is centered (horizontally). If a user comes to this website with a browser window which is slimmer than 1000px in width, he can scroll horizontally. This is what I would like to prevent, since the outer parts of the image are not important and the rest of the page is as wide as the users browser window.

For instance:
A users browser window is 600px in width, what I would like to happen is:

The first 200px of the image are invisible, the next 600px are visible and the last 200px of the image are invisible again.

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="outer" style="width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;">  
        <div id="inner" style="display: table;margin: 0 auto;width:1300px">
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="image" width="1300px">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I came looking for "disable vertical scrolling" and you say *"If a user comes to this website with a browser window which is slimmer than 1000px in width, he can scroll horizontally. This is what I would like to prevent"*.  So I edited the title to "disable horizontal" instead of "disable vertical".  But then I tried overflow-y and overflow-x on a div I was working with and got unexpected results, so perhaps I am missing something...?  So I changed it back.  *I should know better than to try and meddle in CSS questions.  :-)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to use CSS for that.

```
div {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Can you also suggest me how to center the image that the left side disappears when the browser width gets too small? The right side works fine now!

Answer (score 2):

Try `position: fixed;`
This fixes the position and doesn't allow any scrolling

Comment: This is not a good solution, with position fixed, you will not be able to get the div out of your screen without js.

Answer (score 1):

Should work by itself if you just set it as a background image, centered. You'll need to put it on a div that has 100% width applied to it, and a height specified in order to expand the div to see anything.

Comment: Yeah, display it has a background image.

Comment: Although this works on an image, I prefer the answer by user1 which also works on any div. But thx for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with background-size: cover

css

```
main-page { // making a container for demonstration purposes
  display: block; // custom tags need a display, block forces 100% width
  max-width: 1000px; // just matching your image width
  margin: 0 auto; // centering if window is bigger than max-width
}

banner-image {
  display: block; // custom tag needs a display
  height: 80px; // set to the height of your image
  background:
    no-repeat
    url('https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/mountain.jpg')
    50% 50% / cover; // center then cover the element completely
  }
```

HTML note: I'm using custom tags

```
<main-page>
  <banner-image></banner-image>
</main-page>
```